# How to give width in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem with my sticky sidebar. When I scroll down the width automatically get's wider and I don't know why exactly.

My css looks likes this for the sidebar:

```
.wrapper-sticky {
    height: 332px;
    width: 31.66%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: right;

}
.sidebar {
    display:inline-block;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:gray;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    word-spacing: 30px;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

My javascript like this:

```
$(function () {
    var navHeight = $('.sticky').outerHeight(true);
    $('.js-sticky').stickToTop({
        offset: {
            top: 70
        }
    });
});
```

And I gave it 2 script links:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://sdbondi.github.io/jquery-totop/jquery-sticktotop.js"></script>
```

So I thought maybe you can give the width in the javascript? But how?!

Comment: You mean $('.js-sticky').width("30px"); ?

Comment: do you need all of these `left: auto; 
    right: auto; 
    top: auto; 
    bottom: auto;`?

Comment: No I do not. I think I forgot to delete those..Maybe I tried something out but didn't delete. I didn't saw it anymore >_<

Comment: @Dim_Ch yes thanks for the code :). Unfortunately my sidebar still does the same thing. I gave it a width of 275px but there is an element.style and there it says the width is 313px and I don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that your width is in percentage. If you set a fixed width in px, it won't resize.
The CSS would look like this:

```
.wrapper-sticky { width: 275px !important; }
```

Comment: Okay, but it's still getting wider because it automatically gave it an element.style which means it is in the html right? But I don't gave there a code.

The element.style says 313px wide but I gave the .wrapper-sticky div 275px. So, how to change the element style?

Comment: Just say .wrapper-sticky { width: 275px !important; } in the css

Comment: Nevermind! I said in the .sidebar div the width with !important. Now it works.